# How to return the last 9 results for each horse

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have query via sql that lists all a horses performances for previous races. I would like to just list their last 9 performances.

I have been trying to find an answer searching various sites for a while but cannot find one that suits. I would appreciate any help.

```
SELECT Form1.Horse, Form1.Date, Form1.[Mile Rate], Form1.[Beaten M], Form1.Distance, Form1.[M or S], Form1.[Class], Form1.[1Q], Form1.[2Q], Form1.[3Q], Form1.Bar, Form1.Driver, Form1.Comment, Form1.Trainer, Form1.Adj, Form1.[Race%], Form1.[Bell Pos], Form1.Pegs, Form1.[Adj LH], Form1.[M LastL], Form1.[Track]
FROM Form1
WHERE Horse in ('SOHO PICASSO','LITTLE BITOF FUN','BEEJAYS STAR','MISS STARFIRE','MEDIEVAL MAN','BLUE STONE','SOHO MAJOR PLAYER NZ','HUMBLE FELLA','STARS OF GOLD','MISS SERENA','MISS MARGARETA','NIGHTWATCH STAR','PURE IMAGE','VILLAGE BENNY','CAPTAIN CROISSANT','JESSIE JOAN','THE GLASS CEILING','BROOK PARKS LAST','ANTAGONISTIC NZ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function.

```
SELECT*
FROM(
  SELECT Form1.Horse, Form1.Date, Form1.[Mile Rate], Form1.[Beaten M], Form1.Distance, Form1.[M or S], Form1.[Class], Form1.[1Q], Form1.[2Q], Form1.[3Q], Form1.Bar, Form1.Driver, Form1.Comment, Form1.Trainer, Form1.Adj, Form1.[Race%], Form1.[Bell Pos], Form1.Pegs, Form1.[Adj LH], Form1.[M LastL], Form1.[Track]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Horse ORDER BY Date) rn
  FROM Form1
  WHERE Horse in ('SOHO PICASSO','LITTLE BITOF FUN','BEEJAYS STAR','MISS STARFIRE','MEDIEVAL MAN','BLUE STONE','SOHO MAJOR PLAYER NZ','HUMBLE FELLA','STARS OF GOLD','MISS SERENA','MISS MARGARETA','NIGHTWATCH STAR','PURE IMAGE','VILLAGE BENNY','CAPTAIN CROISSANT','JESSIE JOAN','THE GLASS CEILING','BROOK PARKS LAST','ANTAGONISTIC NZ')
)T
WHERE rn <= 9
```

If your DB doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER` use that query:

```
SELECT Form1.Horse, Form1.Date, Form1.[Mile Rate], Form1.[Beaten M], Form1.Distance, Form1.[M or S], Form1.[Class], Form1.[1Q], Form1.[2Q], Form1.[3Q], Form1.Bar, Form1.Driver, Form1.Comment, Form1.Trainer, Form1.Adj, Form1.[Race%], Form1.[Bell Pos], Form1.Pegs, Form1.[Adj LH], Form1.[M LastL], Form1.[Track]
FROM (
  SELECT t1.Horse, t1.Date, COUNT(*) AS rn
  FROM Form1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN Form1 AS t2
  ON t2.Horse = t1.Horse
  AND t2.Date >= t1.Date
  GROUP BY t1.Horse, t1.Date
  HAVING COUNT(*) <= 9
)t
INNER JOIN Form1
ON Form1.Horse = t.Horse
AND Form1.Date = t.Date
```

The inner query simulates the ROW_NUMBER and filters to rows with `rn <= 9`.

Comment: I think this would work best, because you have to factor in Horse and Date to find the last 9 races they all ran.

Comment: Thanks David, Im getting a missing operator in query expression for the line

Comment: Sorry for the line  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Horse ORDER BY Date) rn